# How to get total time for complete binding operation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, performance, binding

i have a complex binding which takes significant time to update. Is there any way to know how much time it takes every time I change (update) the source for binding.

Comment: Take a look at the WPF Performance Suite, AFAIK it allows to measure renering time, could you leverage this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[dotTrace] profiler maybe helpful. There is 10 days trial version available.[1](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)